# Validate few controls using jquery validation engine in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, validation, jquery-validation-engine

I'm using jquery validation engine to validate user inputs in my asp.net web application.
on one page, I need to selective validation.
See this Image
[image]

in this page all fields are required.
but when `Login` is pressed, only `txtUN` and `txtPsw` will be validated, and when `Signup` pressed, `field1`, `field2`, `field3`, `field4`, `field5` will be validated.

Using the following code validates all fields on page if any of those two buttons are pressed.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
     jQuery("#formID").validationEngine();
});
```

Is there any way so that I can achieve my goal? Please help

Answer (score 0):

Put both the div in different form tag and assign different id for both.
And then call the validateEngine() on respective button click.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I can't use multiple  forms in my aspx page.. I'm only allowed to use one form. that is on the master page.

Comment: then call the `validateEngine()` function on each field when the respective button is clicked as, if the login button is clicked then call,
`alert( $("#txtUN").validationEngine('validate') );

alert( $("#txtPsw").validationEngine('validate') );`

and so on...